# Submit App Store Connect Tester feedback directly to JIRA via API or Interface

Tags: app-store, jira, testflight, ios13

In TestFlight 2.3 and iOS 13, testers can send feedback directly from the beta app by taking a screenshot and sharing detailed feedback with a crash report immediately 
after a crash occurs.

Does anyone know of a JIRA web hook and interface so that we may use ITC interface/API to log such issues and directly transmit them to JIRA via an API call?

Answer (score 3):

Recent version of [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools) include an API client for the feedback system. It was added in this PR: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/15793. Sample code from the PR:

```rb
lane :connect_feedback do
  fastlane_require 'spaceship'

  Spaceship::Tunes.login
  Spaceship::Tunes.select_team

  # Gets app
  app = Spaceship::ConnectAPI::App.find(ENV["TEST_APP_BUNDLE"])

  # Gets feedback for an app (default includes screenshots and tester info)
  feedbacks = app.get_beta_feedback

  # Iterate over feedbacks
  feedbacks.each do |feedback|
    puts ""
    puts "comment: #{feedback.comment}"
    puts "name: #{feedback.tester.first_name} #{feedback.tester.last_name}"
    puts "email: #{feedback.tester.email}"
    puts "build: #{feedback.build.version}"

    # Iterate over feedback screenshots
    feedback.screenshots.each do |screenshot|

      # screenshot.image_assets is an array of different resolults of a screenshots
      image_asset = screenshot.image_assets.first

      puts "\turl: #{image_asset["url"]}"
      puts "\twidth: #{image_asset["width"]}"
      puts "\theight: #{image_asset["height"]}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple does **not** provide access to those kind of information via API at the moment.

Check the official docs on what TestFlight information are available: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi

Currently this is mainly around:

- Builds
- Testers

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Max. The url you provided returns a 404. Can you please post the intended uri?

Comment: Done, was missing an "i" at the end, sorry about that.